# How should I route to actions that are not nested that are in a controller that is nested?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested

I have a resource - activities, that is nested under provider.  everything is working great for all my restful resources.

I'd like to add a new action to list all activities regardless of provider.  So I think that should not be nested.

I tried to do this like so:

```
resources :activities, only: [:list]
```

But this doesn't create a route when i rake routes, and I get the error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/activities/list"
```

How do I do this? Is this the right way to go about what I want to do - show a list of all providers activities with a different view / layout than the nested provider#activities  action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.  I (re) read the manual and did what it said, and that worked.  Go figure.

```
resources :activities do
    get 'list', :on => :collection
  end
```

So that adds the list action to the routes with path & url methods & the nested resources still work.